# Keeping track of what's in a Collection in pre-generics Java?

Tags: java, generics, comments

For a bunch of reasons that (believe it or not) are not as unsound as you may think, we are still (*sigh*) using Java 1.4 to build and run our code (though we plan to finally move to Java 7 by the end of the year).

Our existing code that uses `Collection` classes doesn't do a very good job of making it clear what is expected to be in the `Collection`.  Obviously, you can read the code and see what the downcasts end up being done and infer from that, but you can't just look at a method declaration and know what the `Collection` object that is a method argument or method return value actually holds.

In new code that I'm writing and when I am in older code that uses `Collection`s, I've been adding in-line comments to `Collections` declarations to show what would have been declared if generics were being used.  For example:

```
Map/*<String, Set<Integer>>*/ theMap = new HashMap/*<String, Set<Integer>>*/();
```

or

```
List/*<Actions>*/ someMethod(List/*<Job>*/ jobs);
```

In keeping with the frowning at subjectivity here at SO, rather than asking what you think of this (though admittedly I'd like to know -- I do find it a bit ugly but still like having the type info there) I'd instead just ask what, if anything, you do to make it clear what is being held by pre-generics `Collection` objects.

Comment: Java 1.4 to Java 7... cannot imagine what that would be like. Don't really want to, either

Comment: @Matt Ball: I think moving from 1.4 directly to 1.7 is probably less painful than it was to move to 1.5 or 1.6 earlier. Many generics related compiler bugs are now gone and the official javac and eclipse's compiler are slowly converging in what they consider right or wrong. Also 1.7 makes the use of generics a bit more convenient.

Comment: @Matt Ball -- oh, I can.  (Hi Matt.)

Comment: @Matt, Java 1.4 was release 2002, so its a nine year upgrade. :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What we recommended back in the old days -- and I was a Java Architect at Sun when Java 1.1 was the New Thing -- was to write a class around the structure (I don't think 1.1 even had Collection as a base class) so that the typecasts happned in code you control instead of in user code.  So, for example, something like

```
 public class ArrayOfFoo {
     Object [] ary;  // ctor left as exercise

     public void set(int index, Foo value){
         ary[index] = (Object) value; // cast strictly not needed, any Foo is an Object
     }
     public void get(int index){
         return (Foo) ary[index];     // cast needed, not every Object is a Foo
     }
 }
```

Sounds like the code base you have isn't built to this convention; if you're writing new code, there's no reason you can't start.  Failing that, your convention isn't bad, but it's  easy to forget the cast and then have to search to find out why you're getting a bad cast exception.  It's mildly better to resort of some variant on Hungarian notation, or the Smalltalk 'aVariable' convention, by encoding the type in the names, so that you use

```
 Object fooAry = new Object[aZillion];

 fooAry[42] = new Foo();
 Foo aFoo = fooAry[42];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use clear variable identifiers such as `jobList`, `actionList`, or `dictionaryMap`. If you're concerned with the type of objects they contain, you could even make it a convention to always let the identifier of a Collection hint about which type of objects it holds.

The inlined comments aren't that idea actually. When I ported a 1.5 project back to 1.4 I did just that (instead of removing the type parameters). It worked out quite well.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend writing tests. For various reasons:

- You should be writing tests anyway!
- You can assert the type of a collection member very easily to ensure that all your code paths are adding the right types to the collection
- You can use the test to write code that serves as an "example" of how to use the collection correctly

Answer (score 0):

If you just need binary compatibility to 1.4 you could consider using a tool to downgrade the class files back to 1.4 and thus start to develop in 1.6 or 1.7 right now. You would of course need to avoid any API that hasn't been there in 1.4 (unfortunately you can't compile code with generics against the 1.4 jars directly as they don't declare any generic types). The Bytecode is still the same (at least with 1.6, I don't know for sure about 1.7). One free tool that can do the trick is [ProGuard](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/). It can do much more sophisticated things and can also remove all traces of generics in the class files. Just turn off the obfuscation and optimization if you don't need it. It will also warn you if some missing API was used in the processed code if you feed it the 1.4 libraries.

I'm aware that is considered a hack by many but we had a similar requirement where we needed some code to still run on a Personal Java VM (this is essentially Java 1.1) and several other exotic VMs and this approach worked quite well. We started with ProGuard and then made our own tool for the task to be able to implement a few workarounds for some Bugs in the diverse VMs.